# Input element click on mobile device browser behaves differently than in Chrome device rendering

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, samsung-galaxy

I have a hard to debug issue where a click on an input element behaves completely different on my Samsung S10 than in my desktop Chrome browser (also when using device testing tools).

Here's how to test:

- on a small mobile design (max-width: 56em) a blue filter bar appears at the bottom of the screen
- Click it to show all filters, a popup menu appears (you can go back to results by clicking button "Bekijk resultaten")
- Click "+ Specificeer" at the bottom of that screen
- In the small range specification popup that appears click the first input element (placeholder="van")

In Chrome on desktop the user can now enter a number. Also when I use Chrome device debugging tools and set it to iPhoneX, Galaxy S5, Galaxy Fold rendering etcetera it works just fine.

But when I load my live site on my Galaxy S10 in the Chrome browser, the moment the user clicks the input element to enter a number, the rest of the filter popup menu is hidden, and it only shows part of the range specification popup. Scrolling of the page is completely disabled. I'm thinking that certain events are handled differently, but I can't figure out which ones and why.

- I tried monitoring events using `monitorEvents(window,"click");`, but no click events show
- Logged events via Performance tab, but could not find the culprit

I have no idea why anymore and I can't reproduce it in Chrome desktop browser to actually debug it.

**UPDATE 1**

The issue was the mobile virtual keyboard that trigger the `resize` method.
Fixed it by checking for width change:

```
var initialWidth = $(window).width(), initialHeight = $(window).height();

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {

    if ($(window).width() != initialWidth) {//the width was changed
    
    }

})
```

Comment: Have you tried monitoring `touchstart` event instead and see if that is more suitable for your use case?

Comment: My 2 cents is this. We ran into a similar problem a few months back.I did not understand why it was behaving differently in phone vs on chrome device mock. As far as I remember, I think chrome display only deals with the sizes of the devices. It does not change the user agent. That's point number one. So if you want to test on a mobile device try a plugin that helps you change the user agent so you can test on chrome from your computer.


Second would be that the event will be a `touchstart` for you to monitor. The second your user agent changes to an actual phone you're no longer clicking.

Comment: i found that, when the input is in focus and the keyboard pops up, that instant `.mobile` class is removed from `section.filters`. You'll have to see for any event handler that removes the `.mobile` class on any event. Secondly, after the bug was encountered i again added the removed `.mobile` class manually to `section.filters` and the modal was back in place working properly. After clicking `Specificeer` it gives rise to another bug, where the main page becomes unscrollable. Also at the same instant there is another error `TypeError` which could possibly be the cause of the other bug...

Comment: @illusion this was exactly it, it should be the answer

Comment: I'll add it as an answer... XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging, I found that when the input is in focus and the keyboard pops up, that instant `.mobile` class is removed from `section.filters`. You'll have to see for any event handler that removes the `.mobile` class on any event. Secondly, after the bug was encountered I again added the removed `.mobile` class manually to `section.filters` and the modal was back in place working properly. After clicking "Specificeer" it gives rise to another bug, where the main page becomes unscrollable. Also at the same instant there is another error TypeError which could possibly be the cause of the other bug...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've played around. illusion is totally right.

I've copied some styles from .filters .mobile class to .filters_TEST

```
.filters_TEST{
  &.active{
    height: auto;
    flex-grow:1;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF!important;
    min-height: 100vh;

    .modal_container{
      background-color: #fff;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
         height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: hidden;

      #mobilefilters{
        display:block;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

added test button:

```
<span class="js-callmodal display-mobile-only">CALL MODAL</span>
```

and on button click added new class to .

```
$('.js-callmodal').on('click',function(){
  $('.filters_TEST').addClass('active');
});
```

now when you click:
CALL MODAL -> Specificeer -> input
modal stays in place;

to truly fix your problem you should search what removes .mobile class when input is triggered.
I guess the code should be somewhere in file: `_genfuncs.min.js?v=90`